# Update directive when scope variable is updated in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

I have created a directive in which i am parsing a variable "count". In my page there is  a **dropdown** and "count" gets updated whenever **dropdown** value is changed. I have created a directive to show "count". How can i update the directive whenever **dropdown** value is changed.

Code:

```html
<stats count="{{self.shortenedCountArray[2].orignalCount}}"></stats>
```

Directive code:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
       .module('app.pages')
       .directive('stats', stats);
   
       stats.$inject = [ '$rootScope']

   function stats( $rootScope) {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           scope: {},
           templateUrl: 'k2-modules/js/directives/templates/statsTemplate.html',
           link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
            scope.count = attrs.count;
           }
       }
   }
   
})();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Watchers requires some time so if you dont want to next cycle/trigger
  use $apply
- and adding timeout clasure  may need at some situations.

  ```
  link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
    setTimeout ... if needed
     scope.$apply(function () {
      scope.count = attrs.count;
     });
  ```